# How i can Display Unity Game on multi monitors in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to display my unity game on multiple monitors, how I can do this ?

I have already tried the solution from unity documentation but it doesn't work.

**How can I divide one scene in many displays and then play these on multi monitors?**

Answer (score 0):

solution from the documentation works (even if its a bit quirky). BUT in order to have the same scene seperated into multiple views, you need to either

1) Set up seperate cameras for each view. doing this correctly will require you to tweak the projection matrixes, but for some cases this might not be necessary

2) Set your camera to render to a rednertexture, display this texture on a worldspace canvas, set up cameras to view only parts of that render texture. This way is a bit easier to set up but (depending on the resolution) might get slow.

both ways will require additional work if you want anything to be clickable

Comment: thanx if you having any video content on this please send me video link or video please.